# UIImagePickerController camera isn't meant to be "available"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

This may sound dumb, but when I run my application, the `UIImagePickerController` works for Photo Library, but not for Camera importation. I'm guessing this is normal, since my computer is not "connected" to an iPhone camera, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Simulator to try to use the`UIImagePickerController` `Camera` to take a photo. It will not work, You need to test this from an actual device.